# Reading text file, iterating over lines to find a match, and return the value with FSharp

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a text file that contains the following and I need to retrieve the value assigned to taskId, which in this case is *AWc34YBAp0N7ZCmVka2u*.

```
projectKey=ProjectName
serverUrl=http://localhost:9090
serverVersion=10.5.32.3
strong text**interfaceUrl=http://localhost:9090/interface?id=ProjectName
taskId=AWc34YBAp0N7ZCmVka2u
taskUrl=http://localhost:9090/api/ce/task?id=AWc34YBAp0N7ZCmVka2u
```

I have two different ways of reading the file that I've wrote.

```
let readLines (filePath:string) = seq {
 use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
 while not sr.EndOfStream do
     yield sr.ReadLine ()
}

readLines (FindFile currentDirectory "../**/sample.txt")
|> Seq.iter (fun line -> 
   printfn "%s" line
)
```

and

```
let readLines (filePath:string) = 
  (File.ReadAllLines filePath)

readLines (FindFile currentDirectory "../**/sample.txt")
|> Seq.iter (fun line -> 
   printfn "%s" line
)
```

At this point, I don't know how to approach getting the value I need. Options that, I think, are on the table are:

- use Contains()
- Regex
- Record type
- Active Pattern

How can I get this value returned and fail if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the options would be reasonable - it depends on how complex the file will actually be.  If there is no escaping then you can probably just look for `=` in the line and use that to split the line into a key value pair. If the syntax is more complex, this might not always work though.

My preferred method would be to use `Split` on string - you can then `filter` to find values with your required key, `map` to get the value and use `Seq.head` to get the value:

```
["foo=bar"]
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split('='))
|> Seq.filter (fun kvp -> kvp.[0] = "foo")
|> Seq.map (fun kvp -> kvp.[1])
|> Seq.head
```

Using active patterns, you could define a pattern that takes a string and splits it using `=` into a list:

```
let (|Split|) (s:string) = s.Split('=') |> List.ofSeq
```

This then lets you get the value using `Seq.pick` with a pattern matching that looks for strings where the substring before `=` is e.g. `foo`:

```
["foo=bar"] |> Seq.pick (function
  | Split ["foo"; value] -> Some value
  | _ -> None)
```

The active pattern trick is quite neat, but it might be unnecessarily complicating the code if you only need this in one place.

Comment: Thanks Tomas - I appreciate you providing an explanation on the two options.